# Accessing historical data for validators from the API

Tags: polkadot, validator, api, python

I have been trying to pull the validator-level data for Polkadot for a project I am working on. I am using [this API](https://support.subscan.io) and have been unable to find a command I need. Ideally, the request URL would either return the number of validators for each day/era/epoch (any of those work), or even better, would return validator-level information for each validator staking during each day/era/epoch. I see requests for current validator information, but I can't see how to access historical data.

Does anyone know of a request URL that would work for this, or another API which would have this information? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into this tool [substrate-api-sidecar](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar), it makes easy to interact with blockchain nodes via API queries.

Connect the tool into your local network or into Polkadot creating a .env file with:

```
SAS_SUBSTRATE_URL=wss://rpc.polkadot.io
```

Take a look here in all the queries available with the tool: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate-api-sidecar/dist/

You can query the staking data in a certain block with `/pallets/staking/progress` or payouts and info of certain accounts with the queries `/accounts/{accountId}/staking-payouts`  and `/accounts/{accountId}/staking-info`

Comment: Just to add to what Alex said; you can use the `?at=<blocknumber or hash>` query parameter with the `/pallets/staking/progress` endpoint to get the list of addresses in the validatorSet at a historic block.

NOTE: you will need to be querying an archive node if you wish to get all historic data.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the subscan API, I also couldn't find a way to pull validator-level data from a historic session.

However, you can find the [session info](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/143a30874f618c9f3c1e8eca09a526e432382572/roadmap/implementers-guide/src/runtime/session_info.md) for a given sessionIndex by using [this call](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/runtime#sessioninfoindex-sessionindex-optionsessioninfo) from the polkadot.js API. As sessions on polkadot are the [same length as epochs](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-polkadot-parameters), you can get the current session index, and then just decrement the index to query backwards and get a list of validators for each past epoch.

There may be an undocumented way to do this in subscan, but based only on API documentation, this is probably the best way.